# Celery - How many queues?

Tags: celery

I am using Celery with RabbitMQ as a broker.

My project will consist of some long running sequential groups of tasks.  The output of the previous set of tasks is the input for the next set of tasks.

All of the worker nodes will first consume the first type (group) of tasks, then all the workers will consume the next type of tasks, with the previous result as input, etc, sequentially.

My question is, in Celery, how many queues should I define?
Only 1 queue for all the tasks? Or should I use 1 queue for each type of tasks?
What is the benefit of using 1 queue or more queues in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the queues, so that there were two. From a flow of information point of view the two separate queues makes more sense. It also explicitly says that the information flows across this path and all the tasks in any one of the queues are similar.

So, the benefit to multiple queues is that the tasks are separated from each other in a logical sense. Making the flow of information easier to follow. If your task queue gets rather large then designing with multiple queues in mind also applies redundancy into the system as you can separate out the queues to different machines if the need arises. Using Celery Routing you can separate which machines listen to which queue and separate your tasks out to various other machines.

The benefit of a single queue is that it is simple to use and easier to setup, but you lose the fine grained control of where/who performs the task work. And, the flow of information is not as clear from a logical stand point.